# creating vm and running installation script in azure

Tags: azure, deployment, automation, devops

I'm looking for a way to run a script that creates a simple windows vm with rdp port and installs a software on it in order give our clients a simple sand boxed server for testing purposes. Is there a simple way to do that as I've been struggling for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows) for Azure VM. Depending on how you create vms you can use powershell\cli\arm templates\rest api\sdk to use that extension.

sample powershell:

```
$ProtectedSettings = @{"commandToExecute" = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\filesvr\build\serverUpdate1.ps1"};

Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName myRG 
    -Location myLocation ` 
    -VMName myVM ` 
    -Name "serverUpdate" 
    -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" `
    -ExtensionType "CustomScriptExtension" ` 
    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.9" `
    -ProtectedSettings $ProtectedSettings
```

ARM Template sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows
AZ cli sample: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2017/02/13/executing-custom-script-extension-using-azure-cli-2-0-on-an-azure-linux-virtual-machine/